# python custom metaclass call method relation with classes

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to understand the relation in between python **metaclass** and **class**. I was trying to create singleton class and found this code

```
class SingleTon(type):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._instances is None:
            self._instances = super(SingleTon, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return self._instances

class Counter:
    __metaclass__ = SingleTon
    _instances = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 1
c = Counter()
```

my question here is how counter class object is getting created using **metaclass**. I know **metaclass** **call** method gets called whenever we create an object but  the confusion is here what this code  **super(SingleTon, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)** does here. Please explain. It would be very appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super` will just forward the arguments to `type.__call__` which is responsible for the class creation.

It's like calling `super` in a 'normal' class hierarchy only now, you're calling it in a metaclass. Since `SingleTon` is a subclass of `type`, that'll get called. In a class scenario, you'd (normally) forward calls to the base class `object`.

Comment: So, that means i can use type directly instead of super ??

Comment: Yup, try it out! (pass `self` too, though). That beats the point of using `super`, though (you're hard-coding names).

Comment: Thank you very much jim. Please clear one more thing type(metaclass) method __call__ is responsible for creating instance object. Then how also it creates the class ?

Comment: @dheerajsaini That's a loaded question to be honest :-). To keep it as short as I can: `type.__call__` handles both cases, depending on what is passed to it either `type.__new__/__init__` (or `mymetaclass.__new__/__init__` in general) is going to get called for classes or `object.__new__/__init__` or (`class.__new__/__init__`) for instances.